# What are problems created by Rahu Kethu and Shani grahas?

Tags: astrology, navagraha, shani

Problems are problems right, but why we have 3 different grahas to create problems?

Are there any differences in the problems created by Rahu, Kethu, Shani grahas and what are they?

Comment: Every Planet gives both good and bad results depending on multiple configurations. Indeed good and bad is subjective. For example, for Vrishabha and tula lagna people Shani becomes Raja yoga planet and does good in some aspects. Rahu does very well in 6th Bhava of disputes and enemies and Ketu is Moksha Karaka. So, we can say these planets as both good and bad depending on positions and other factors.